# Having a same y-axes height for subplots in R

Tags: r, plot, scale, subplot, yaxis

I am trying to three subplots that differ in maximum y-axes to have same height. It seems that by default, R only writes y-axis ticks at even numbers but I would like to have the y-axes of the subplots to have the same height (and hence same margin between the plots and the title) even when the maximum y-axes are different.

Here are my codes:

```
df <- data.frame(mean.1 <- c(0.8, 0.7), sd.1 <- c(0.07, 0.1),
    mean.2 <- c(14, 11), sd.2 <- c(5.2, 8.1),
    mean.3 <- c(3.5, 5.5), sd.3 <- c(1.4, 0.3)
    )

# Global setting
par(mfcol = c(1, 3),
    mar = c(4, 4, 3, 2), tcl = -0.5, mgp = c(3, 1, 0),
    oma = c(2, 2, 2, 2), las = 1
    )

# Subplot 1
subplot.1 <- barplot(mean.1,
            names.arg = c('A', 'B'),
            main = 'Subplot 1',
            ylab = 'Mean for subplot 1',
            col = c('blue', 'red'),
            border = NA,
            ylim = c(0, (max(mean.1) + max(sd.1))*1.2)
            )
# Error bars
arrows(subplot.1, mean.1 - sd.1, subplot.1, mean.1 + sd.1,
    col = c('blue', 'red'),
    length = 0.05, angle = 90,
    code = 2
    )

# Subplot 2
mean.2 <- c(14, 11)
sd.2 <- c(5.2, 8.1)

subplot.2 <- barplot(mean.2,
            names.arg = c('A', 'B'),
            main = 'Subplot 2',
            ylab = 'Mean for subplot 2',
            col = c('blue', 'red'),
            border = NA,
            ylim = c(0, (max(mean.2) + max(sd.2))*1.2)
            )
# Error bars
arrows(subplot.2, mean.2 - sd.2, subplot.2, mean.2 + sd.2,
    col = c('blue', 'red'),
    length = 0.05, angle = 90,
    code = 2
    )

# Subplot 3
mean.3 <- c(3.5, 5.5)
sd.3 <- c(1.4, 0.3)

subplot.3 <- barplot(mean.3,
            names.arg = c('A', 'B'),
            main = 'Subplot 3',
            ylab = 'Mean for subplot 3',
            col = c('blue', 'red'),
            border = NA,
            ylim = c(0, (max(mean.3) + max(sd.3))*1.2)
            )
# Error bars
arrows(subplot.3, mean.3 - sd.3, subplot.3, mean.3 + sd.3,
    col = c('blue', 'red'),
    length = 0.05, angle = 90,
    code = 2
    )
```

Here is what I currently get.

[image: Output plot]

Comment: Oh, I totally misunderstood your question. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for willing to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ggplot. First I'm using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to transform the data according the required ggplot format. Then plotting the data using  `facet_wrap()` with `scales = "free_y"` to get different y-axis scales.

```
library(tidyverse)
# The data
df = data.frame(mean.1 = c(0.8, 0.7), sd.1 = c(0.07, 0.1),
                 mean.2 = c(14, 11), sd.2 = c(5.2, 8.1),
                 mean.3 = c(3.5, 5.5), sd.3 = c(1.4, 0.3))
# Pipeline
library(tidyverse)
df %>% select(-starts_with("sd")) %>% 
  bind_cols(group=c("A","B")) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -group) %>%
  bind_cols(sd=c(sd.1,sd.2,sd.3)) %>% 
  mutate(key=rep(paste("Subplot", 1:3), each = 2)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=group, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-sd, ymax=value+sd, col=group), width=0.1) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Using base R I have no straightforward solution. I recommend to play around using `ylim=c()` and the `axis()` function in case of to small y-axis like follows:

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 3))
barplot(df$mean.1, ylim=c(0, round(max(df$mean.1 + df$sd.1))))
barplot(df$mean.2, ylim=c(0, round(max(df$mean.2 + df$sd.2))), axes=F)
axis(2, at=c(0, seq(1, 20, 2)))
barplot(df$mean.3, ylim=c(0, round(max(df$mean.3 + df$sd.3))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering! Does basic R function allow to do this?

Comment: Thanks! I guess using base R function, there is no quick and easy way to have same y-axes heights but you can individually set them.